# The current path, didn't match any of these. error django

Tags: python, django

> Page not found (404)
>      Request Method:    GET>br>
>      Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/votes/
>       Using the URLconf defined in votes.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>      ^$ [name='index']
>      The current path, votes/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

this is my urls.py of my app.

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

this is my urls of my entire project

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^votes/', include('votes.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I tried to approach to admin site but i couldn't. how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you add the urls defined in your app votes also?

Comment: did you try to restart the server

Comment: I restarted and nothing has been changed. I just started python with django and still can not understand how to fix

Comment: @ddalu5 the first one above is it

Comment: Did you put the `votes` app to INSTALLED_APPS in `settings.py`?

Comment: @PhuongNguyen yes I did

Answer (score 1):

In your app urls.py your saying that: http://127.0.0.1:8000/ should call votes.views.index not http://127.0.0.1:8000/votes/, so you need to change it to:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^votes/$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: I mean there is something wrong with the path of admin - site

Comment: but does http://127.0.0.1:8000/votes/ works? because django is checking the votes urls before the admin ones